# Magento 2 Data migration for only customers, categories and coupons

Tags: magento2, migration, data

I want to migrate data(only **customers, categories and coupons**) from **magento 1.9.0.1(CE)** to **magento 2.1.0(CE)**

I am following Steps from -  http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-install.html for data migration.

What I understood is in
1. **m2project/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.0.1/config.xml** I defined source and destination database table and map.xml 
And after that I run setting, data and delta migration

I am stuck with step data migration with error :

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '1-Migration_Default' for key
>   'EAV_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ENTITY_TYPE_ID_ATTRIBUTE_SET_NAME'

If any help to solve this error, will make me proceed migration.

Also, I am unclear about :

1. What exactly data it transfers other that **customers,orders, products**.
2. If I have multiple stores in **magento1.9** and here in **magento2.1** I want single store in that case what will happen? because product will be having dependency on store.
3. I want yo know how to migrate only customers, categories and coupons.

Comment: Please answer your own question

Comment: It seems mapping is not done properly with all tables thats reason of above error. And i posted answer too. If you have already sorted out then post answer. If not then post comment so I try to sort out.

Answer (score 2):

Migration tool migrate can migrate all-settings, products, categories, orders, customers, product review and linked-product relation(cross sell, related products) etc. Basically it migrate everything.

If you have multiple store, It can migrate all stores and linked data with all stores. You can delete/filter migrated data on Magento2 store. It may be possible to migrate data of one store but I dont know about that.

I can explain how only customers can be migrated and all data can be migrated. Thats what i already achieved. You can delete extra data which is not required.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to this post from a guy that successfully did something similar.
https://www.pinpointdesigns.co.uk/migrating-data-from-magento-1-to-magento-2-using-the-data-migration-tool/

It might help you to understand how data migration tool works and how you can adapt it to achieve what you need.